# How to pass an object to a reducer with state key

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm building an app with React Native and I'm trying to record audio. I would like to pass an object to my action and then further to my reducer in order to update the state.

In my screen where I call the action:

```
this.props.recordAudio({ stoppedRecording: true, recording: false, paused: false });
```

Action:

```
export const recordAudio = (change) => {
  return {
    type: AUDIO,
    payload: change
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  audio: {
    recording: false,
    paused: false,
    stoppedRecording: false,
  }
}

case AUDIO:
return {
  ...state,
  audio: {
    ...state.audio,
    [action.payload]
  }
}
```

I get an error: Unexpected token (Fatal). I also tried without brackets.

I have other keys inside audio and it's easier to update them all by directly passing key/value, instead of making a separate action for all of them. Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should spread Object action.payload like:

```
 case AUDIO:
        return {
          ...state,
          audio: {
            ...state.audio,
            ...action.payload
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case audio:
return {
      ...state,
  audio: {
      ...state.audio,
    [action.payload]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the square bracket

```js
case AUDIO:
return {
  ...state,
  audio: {
    ...state.audio,
    ...action.payload
  }
}
```

Comment: hm, that's what i thought but i get `Unexpected token, expected "," ` when i try it like this

Comment: @TomBomb: I made a mistake, you should spread the `action.payload` since it's an object